# 2-level prefetch on reverse foreign key with select_subclasses

Tags: django, django-1.8

I have been working on 2-level reverse foreignkey with the second level one having inherited subclasses. I am using django-model-utils for the inheritance. I kept tweaking prefetch commands without use until I found an answer to traverse the queryset in this post
[Prefetch object with multiple levels of reverse lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358729/prefetch-object-with-multiple-levels-of-reverse-lookups)

My questions are,
1)I dont see the inner join with the reverse foreign key tables when I print the query. Is that because prefetch pulls them in a separate query?

```
print product_types.query
```

2)Do the .all() in the traversals, hit the database? or does django pull the data from a single prefetch?

```
pt.bevtank_set.all()
```

3)In general, any tips on how I can figure out what I am really querying? I dont want to be doing something that meets my needs but doing something that is the right way of meeting my needs.

Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `prefetch_related` fetches the related tables in a separate query, so you don't see inner joins.

If you have prefetched the the `bevtank_set`, then `pt.bevtank_set.all()` will not cause any additional queries. However `pt.bevtank_set.filter()` will cause additional queries. You can use the [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) object in Django 1.7+ to prefetch a filter the prefetched queryset.

Regarding general tips, [Django Debug Toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/) can be useful to view SQL queries. If there are duplicated queries, it's often an indication that you could add a `select_related` or `prefetch_related` to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for the toolbar tip! I have a follow up question.
So I did actually Prefetch class since I had to call the select_subclasses() on the second level. What would be the preferred way of handing over this data to the template for display? Typically I pull the required fields using values() and hand over just this data to the template for rendering. In this case I cant calls the values(), right since there is no inner join. Do I need to generate a separate dict by traversing and then hand over that, to the template?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your data model, so I don't know the best way for you to pass it to the template. If creating a separate dict in the view works for you, that sounds ok.